# referring attributes in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
class Account
    attr_accessor :balance

    def initialize (amount=0)
        self.balance = amount
    end

    def -(x)
        self.balance -= x
    end

    def +(x)
        self.balance += x
    end 

    def to_s
        puts "Balance is #{self.balance} !!!!!!!!!"
    end


end

acc = Account.new(20)
acc -=5
```

Can someone explain why it works to write: `puts acc` (render 15 as a result) but this line:
`puts acc.balance` doesn't work (it says `undefined method balance`, however it's not a method, it should be seen as a property/attribute)
Thanks in advance

Comment: What purpose does the `attr_accessor` serve here? Why not just use `@balance`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of your error is line

```
acc -= 5
```

it assings result (returned value) of substraction method to acc variable, and this result is `Fixnum` instance, which doesn't have `balance` method defined.

If you want your `+` and `-` methods to return `Account` instance, you need to specify this:

```
def +(x)
  self.balance += x
  self
end
```

etc.

BTW, accessors in Ruby ARE methods.

Answer (score 4):

`acc -= 5` is equivalent to `acc = acc - 5`.

`acc - 5` is `15` (by `Account#-` method); `acc = acc - 5` is like `acc = 15`.

Now `acc` is Fixnum object.

---

How about implement `+`, `-` as follow?

```
def -(x)
    Account.new(self.balance - x)
end

def +(x)
    Account.new(self.balance + x)
end
```

Comment: I understand taht the "-" method is used to withdraw money from the current account balance, so was not surprised about the result 15. But still don't understand why `puts acc.balance` doesn't work. Isn't `balance` an `attribute` of every `instance`? Maybe my syntax is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @Sam, According to your code, the return value of `-`, `+` method is `Fixnum`, not a `Balance` instance.

Comment: @Sam, I added alternative implementation of `-`, `+`; which return a new `Account` instance instead of `Fixnum`.

Comment: @Sam You must be aware that methods implemented in this way will return new `Account` instance, leaving original (`self`) unaffected. It may or may not be desired.

Comment: @MarekLipka, I know, that is intended. Think about `account1 + 5`. Implementing in your way, it changes the balance of `account1`. Normally that is unexpected side effect.

Comment: @falsetru that's what I thought, I wanted to make sure OP is aware.

Answer (score 1):

You want to edit your two methods to make `+=` and `-=` work, so that they return the object in place:

```
def -(x)
    self.balance -= x
    self
end

def +(x)
    self.balance += x
    self
end
```

That way, the object it reassigned to itself.

Answer (score 1):

Oops, there is a number of things that have been wrong with this one. I cannot explain all the problems, but let's see how far I can get:

First of all you have redefined the `#+` and `#-` methods to give them semantics you would expect from `#+=` and `#-=`. Given this: if you use `acc-5` in your example (instead of `acc-=5`) the behavior is close to what you expect, `irb` will display `15` as this is the result of your `#-` method (which has the side effect of subtracting 5 of balance as well).

However, as you call `#-=` in your example the ruby interpreter ends up assigning the methods result `Fixnum` `15` to your `acc`-variable. This will give you the error message `NoMethodError: undefined method 'balance' for 15:Fixnum` when you try to access `#balance` which happens to be defined on your `Account` class.

Your `#-` method should return an `Account`-object, not change the existing state of the object and return the result as a `Fixnum`. See http://ruby.about.com/od/oo/ss/Overloading-Operators.htm for examples on how to redefine operators. I understand that this somehow defeats your purpose as you would have liked to use `#-=` to modify the object in place, but it only works by creating another `Account`-instance in Ruby as you are not able to redefine `#-=` directly (see the link above).

Of course you are free to define a `#withdraw`-method to get the semantics you desire.